# add element in nested Array, mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
   "_id": {
        "$oid": "61ba1c3862f54f0a0a32c163"
      },
   "answersArray": {
       "5f57df4018dbc4038465b246": [
         {
           "content": "<p>dsasa</p>",
           "userid": "lorem123"
         },
         // need to add object like this mentioned below
         {
           "content": "<p>My new content</p>",
           "userid": "lorem ipsome"
         }
        ]
   }
}
```

I wanted to add as well as update if userid does not exist in 5f57df4018dbc4038465b246 array using mongo.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? what exactly is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert updated Question. I want mongo query to add object in array

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.getCollection('answers')
    .update(
      {'answersArray._id': 1}, 
      { $push : 
      {'answersArray.5f57df4018dbc4038465b246' : {'userID':'ll'} 
    }
  })
```

Finally able to push element in array using `$push`